# python multiprocessing of finite element simulation processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a Python tool that will automatically do a number of operations for me.  One part of the automation is the parallel processing of n number of LSDYNA finite element simulations.  I want to send the n simulations to a pool and have them distributed to a user specified number of processors, x.  As one simulation terminates, another should be sent from the pool to the idle processor until the pool is empty.  At this time, the rest of the python code should continue to execute.  If this code were working correctly on my Windows machine, I would expect to see x number of cmd windows running LSDYNA at any time (until to pool is empty).

I have read a number of similar questions and they all seem to end up using the multiprocessing module.  I've written a code that I thought was correct however, when I execute it, nothing happens.  There are no error messages in the terminal window, and I do not get any LSDYNA output.

I do have a windows batch script that does work and does the same thing, in case that would be helpful to anyone.

In case I'm doing something completely wrong, a note about LSDYNA:  When run via command line, each simulation runs in its own terminal window.  The output files are written to the current directory at the time of command execution.  The command format is:

```
"C:\LSDYNA\program\ls971_s_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe" i=input.k ncpu=1 memory=100m
```

This is the Python code that I've come up with:

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess
import glob

def run_LSDYNA(individual_sim_dir, model_name, solver_path):

    os.chdir(individual_sim_dir)

    os.environ['lstc_license'] = 'network'
    os.environ['lstc_license_server'] = 'xxx.xx.xx.xx'

    subprocess.call([solver_path, "i=%s" % model_name, "ncpu=1", "memory=100m"])

def parallel(sim_dir, procs, model_name, solver_path):

    run_dirs = []

    for individual_sim_dir in glob.glob(os.path.join(sim_dir, 'channel_*')):
        run_dirs.append(individual_sim_dir)

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=procs)

    args = ((run_dir, model_name, solver_path) for run_dir in run_dirs)
    simulations = pool.map_async(run_LSDYNA, args)

    simulations.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.freeze_support()
    parallel('C:\Users\me\Desktop\script_test\Lower_Leg_Sims', 2, 'boot.k', "C:\LSDYNA\program\ls971_s_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong here, but you might want to look at popen. It already spawns a new process (so does call, but popen doesn't block like call does) so you don't have to do anything with multiprocessing. To do this you would popen n instances, poll them in a loop and open a new one each time one finishes.

Comment: One possibly problem is the call to pool.map_async. I'm not positive, but I think the function passed in here can only take one argument (look at the diffrence between map and itertools.starmap). If that was the problem I would have expected to see an exception though.

Comment: I'll look into avoiding the multiprocessing, @Matt.  In other news, by throwing in some random print statements, it appears that the "run_LSDYNA" function is never being called.  Haven't been able to figure out why though...